# SOLVED: Installing ethernet driver in Kubuntu 14.04 without internet connection

Tags: drivers, ethernet

I have installed Kubuntu 14.04 (desktop version).  I wish to install Ethernet drivers. I have two ethernet ports and I found that the drivers that I need are e1000e and igb-5.2.13-k.  I have downloaded the .tar.gz driver files  from Intel website.

I have done the following steps:

tar zxf e1000e-3.2.4.2.tar.gz

cd e1000e-3.2.4.2.tar.gz

cd src

make install

It says

Makefile:121: *** Compiler not found. Stop.

What should I do?

Additional Information: I cannot use internet to do sudo apt-get (some packages) to install compiler or others. I have entered the IP, Gateway and I am able to ping the gateway nicely meaning there is no problem with the network connection. Only the Ethernet driver is not installed. Anyone have come across this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can ping any Gateway, you don't need an ethernet driver, because ethernet is already working.

From what you described, I would say your network setup is just wrong. You most probably need to configure a proper routing setup so that your host knows how to get to the outside world. If available in your network, try first using DHCP.

Now, depending on the kind of Ubuntu setup you are running (Ubuntu, Kubuntu, pure server Ubuntu), you might want to review different articles for configuring that:

- Gnome: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager
- KDE: http://www.kubuntu.org/docs/kquickguide/C/ch02s06.html
- terminal guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I cannot ping www.google.com... What should I do?

Comment: Sure, your host can't resolve hostnames yet. You need to tell it where your gateway and nameserver is. Please read up on your own about how to configure networking in Ubuntu. I can't do the reading for you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment...I will read it...BTW i can ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: That means even gateway is configured correctly. The only part missing is setting nameserver. In most cases, this is the same as gateway. But of course you could also use Google's nameserver under 8.8.8.8

Comment: Thanks i edited the file resolv.conf and it is working nicely..

Comment: Now let's hope those changes are preserved on next reboot. If not, some network manager is interfering and you need to check with this tool how to make those changes permanent.